# Opening a link from the console in the safari mobile

Tags: ios, iphone, safari

I know that in Chrome console I can use the command `open("https://www.google.com")` to load google into the current tab, what I want to know is an equivalent command on the safari console on iPhones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need anything more fancy than `window.location.href = "https://www.google.com`